# Oracle sql update using regexp_replace

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sql-update

I have almost 2000 rows in a table ("Sensor", which has many more than 2000 rows) in which I need to update one column, the sensorname.

Part of the replacement within the update is based on the contents of another table, deviceport.

Deviceport is related to the updating table through this deviceportid column -- sensor.deviceportid = deviceportid.  Thus the actual update is different for every row.  I don't want to have to write 2000 update statements, but I haven't been able to figure out what my "where" statement will say.

```
UPDATE sensor sn SET sn.sensorname = ( 
    SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
        sensorname, 
        '^P(\d)', 
        'J ' || (
                SELECT d.deviceportlabel 
                FROM deviceport d 
                WHERE d.deviceportid = s.deviceportid
                ) || 
       ' Breaker \1'
    )
    FROM sensor s 
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( sensorname, '^P(\d)') 
) 
WHERE ...?
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE sensor sn 
SET sn.sensorname = 'J ' || 
   (
     SELECT d.deviceportlabel 
     FROM deviceport d 
     WHERE d.deviceportid = sn.deviceportid
   ) || ' Breaker ' || substr(sn.sensorname, 2, 1)
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( sn.sensorname, '^P\d')
```

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert - My code is very similar to OP's code.  What exactly you did not understand?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
UPDATE sensor sn, deviceport d 
SET sn.sensorname = REGEXP_REPLACE(
        sn.sensorname,'^P(\d)', 'J '|| d.deviceportlabel||' Breaker \1')
WHERE d.deviceportid = sn.deviceportid
AND REGEXP_LIKE( sn.sensorname, '^P(\d)');
```