# Oracle Update with Regular Expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have some values in a column like:

"This is test $ABC variables."

I want to update all the variable definition to below one:

"This is test $ABC$ variables."

How can I write this update statement? Somehow, I couldn't manage.

Comment: Its a good idea to show us what you have already tried. Take a look at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for help with writing a question.

Comment: You need to provide a very careful and complete definition of "variable". Is that a string that begins with a dollar sign and ends at the first space (or end of string)? Or does it end at any non-alphanumeric character? What can be BEFORE the dollar sign - spaces? Other characters? Does a variable name always begin with a letter? (Otherwise $133.23 will be seen as a variable.) Etc. Without a super air-tight definition, if you go ahead and update the values in the column without thinking about all these exceptions, you will create a big mess.

Comment: the answer I was looking for was here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176023/714112

Answer (score 3):

Do you just want `replace()`?

```
update t
    set col = replace(col, '$ABC', '$ABC$')
     where col like '%$ABC%';
```

Comment: I know this is a very short answer but a downvote for something that answers the question as asked seems a bit harsh.

Comment: @BriteSponge - And, a downvote without a Comment to state one's objection (the reason for the downvote) is asinine. Alas, that is very common on this site.

Comment: With that said, this is a really poor answer. It hardcodes the variable name; it is very unlikely that the OP's text includes only one variable name, hardcoded as in Gordon's answer. This is one of Gordon's laziest answers I am aware of.

Comment: The problem here is the ambiguity in the question, not Gordon's simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `REGEXP` query. The parentheses in `'\$(\w+)'` capture the word following `$` in `\1`

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (
          'This is test $ABC variables.This is a second variable $variable2.I have 100$',
          '\$(\w+)',
          '$\1$')
  FROM DUAL;
```

**O/p:**

```
This is test $ABC$ variables.This is a second variable $variable2$.I have 100$
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not good at regular expressions so this poor attempt of mine could probably be replaced by something smarter. Looking forward to see it!

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select 'This is test $ABC variables' col from dual union
  3     select 'Stackoverflow says $DEF is so cool' from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6    col,
  7    regexp_replace(col, '\$\w+',  regexp_substr(col, '\$\w+') || '$') result
  8  from test;

COL                                RESULT
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
Stackoverflow says $DEF is so cool Stackoverflow says $DEF$ is so cool
This is test $ABC variables        This is test $ABC$ variables

SQL>
```